# Causes of emission of accretion disk

Tags: black-hole, quasars, accretion-discs

As far as I can see, there are two main sources for the emission of energy from an accretion disk:

- release of gravitational potential energy of the infalling matter;
- friction from differential rotation within the disk.

How much of the emitted energy is due to each process? For that matter, are there any other processes that contribute to the spectrum?